# What does "half an idea" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), Dallas speaks to his lover Susie for last time:

> Dallas: I came here with **half an idea** of saying good-bye... but I
> guess I'll hang around...to plead.

What does "half an idea" mean? Is it equal to "half baked idea"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have half an idea to do something, you haven't decided to do it, but are thinking seriously about doing it. He was 50% sure that he wanted to say good-bye. We say (past tense) 'I **had** half an idea' to mean 'I was tentatively planning to do something, but I ended up doing something else instead.' We can say (present tense) 'I **have** half an idea...' to mean 'I might do (whatever it is) or I might not'.

> I had half an idea to see a movie at a cinema, but it started to rain
> so I stayed home instead.

We can also say (especially in the UK) that we have 'half a mind' to do something, with the same meaning. This is often, but not always, because we are annoyed about something. If we say we have a 'good mind' to do something then that is more likely to be because we are angry.

> I had half a mind to complain to the restaurant manager after the
> waiter was rude.

[Half a mind/good mind (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-half-a-mind-a-good-mind-to)

Answer (score 0):

'Half an idea' means that the idea exists and is fully formed, but that the person using the expression is not fully committed to it. It is just a possibility.

*e.g. I came here with half an idea of resigning.* == "I came here considering whether I should resign."

It is the same as 'I had half a mind to ...'

Confusingly, particularly when used in a past tense, it's generally used when the user has more or less abandoned the idea.